# Positioning labels to an existing empty plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

Can you help me in correctly positioning labels to an existing empty plot using `tikz` ?

My problems are:

- my labels are too far from the axes;
- my labels are not centered.

---

Here is the empty plot

[image]

and here is what I currently do to superimpose axis labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (plot) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plot.pdf}};
\node at (plot.west) {$y$};
\node at (plot.south) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My graphic.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Comment: The easiest way for this particular problem would be `\node at ([xshift=1cm]plot.west) {$y$};` and `\node at ([yshift=1cm]plot.south) {$x$};` where you will replace `1cm` with needed distance. But I'd suggest to draw the complete graphic with `pgfplots`. You will find a lot of examples and help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that the labels are too far away because the pdf file contains a lot of white space around the graph. You can use the `trim` option of `\includegraphics` to effectively trim that unwanted white space, like so :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (plot) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7, trim=1cm 1cm 0 0]{plot.pdf}};
    \node at (plot.west) {$y$};
    \node at (plot.south) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My graphic.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where in `trim=l b r t`, `l`, `b`, `r` and `t` correspond to left, bottom, right and top respectively. Hopefully, this would also solve the centering problem.

Comment: Looks nice! I did not know the trim option. Let me try and I will probably accept your answer very soon.